# Self sizing cells Supporting in IOS 9 and not supporting in IOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I am new to swift in my app I have a concept that is increase the custom cells dynamically for that purpose. I followed the following tutorial [Understanding Self Sizing Cells and Dynamic Type in iOS 8](http://%20Understanding%20Self%20Sizing%20Cells%20and%20Dynamic%20Type%20in%20iOS%208][1])
][1](http://%20Understanding%20Self%20Sizing%20Cells%20and%20Dynamic%20Type%20in%20iOS%208][1]) . Every thing working fine in IOS 9 devices but when test in IOS 8.2 devices  custom cells are not increasing Present i am using XCODE 7.0.1 any one have idea regarding this issue if yes? please tell me

```
  override func viewdidappear() 
  {   
  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
  tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  tableView.reloaddata()
  }
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGfloat
```

{  return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 }

Comment: Show your code and you'll get better results here.